# How to compact/group by the results of a query by columns' values?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, group-by, aggregate

I have the following table (MySQL version >= 5.7.X, using DBeaver 21.1.0 to manage the db):

| n_brand | population | actions_completed_by_unique_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pepsico | pepsicoeur | 1 |
| pepsico | pepsicoeur | 1 |
| pepsico | pepsicoeur | 1 |
| pepsico | pepsicousa | 1 |
| pepsico | pepsicousa | 2 |
| pepsico | pepsicousa | 2 |
| pepsico | pepsicomex | 0 |
| pepsico | pepsicomex | 2 |
| ferrari | ferrarieur | 1 |
| ferrari | ferrarieur | 1 |
| ferrari | ferrariusa | 0 |
| ferrari | ferrarimex | 1 |
| ferrari | ferrarimex | 1 |

I would like to have something like (I don't necessarily require the grouping column to be named actions_completed_by_unique_user, would be a nice to have):

| n_brand | population | actions_completed_by_unique_user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pepsico | pepsicoeur | 3 |
| pepsico | pepsicousa | 5 |
| pepsico | pepsicomex | 2 |

My query is:

```
SELECT n_brand , population, actions_completed_by_unique_user
FROM agg_table
WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'
AND actions_completed_by_unique_user > 0
GROUP BY population
```

But it only takes the first occurrence of each population and doesn't sum the values, is it possible to do this just using SQL querying or do I have to do this programatically?

Comment: I extensively revised my answer - you may wish to take a look?

Comment: thanks @Vérace, the 2th iteration of the question really made me re-look core concepts (I'm still revising some stuff) & to really pay attention to the sql_mode config, it never crossed my mind to make to double check that (to get deterministic results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve this, I did the following. All the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e5d41db6daf4dc7e633c616d3d2b9983).

I took another look at this and realised that my first answer (see edit history) had merely "handed you a fish", rather than "teaching you how to fish([*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime))"!

### Overview:

You have **two** issues here, one easy enough to spot and deal with - aggregation - in this case, `SUM()`-ing over and then `GROUP`-ing `BY` certain fields (see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) - (`"compact"`-ing in the question) and the other problem is more subtle:

- MySQL **in this case** doesn't perform `GROUP BY` correctly! **"What??"**, I hear you say, **"the most popular Open Source server can't do a simple query??"**. And the answer is that, in this case, sadly, **"No, it can't!"**.

### Part 1 - clarification of MySQL's GROUP BY:

This latter issue is potentially both more harmful and confusing, and requires clarification before answering the question, so I will deal with it first.

The first thing to do is to create a `test` table and populate it with your data:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  n_brand VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  population VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
  actions_u_user INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

data:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('pepsico', 'pepsicoeur',   1),
('pepsico', 'pepsicoeur',   1),
('pepsico', 'pepsicoeur',   1),
('pepsico', 'pepsicousa',   1),
('pepsico', 'pepsicousa',   2),
('pepsico', 'pepsicousa',   2),
('pepsico', 'pepsicomex',   0),
('pepsico', 'pepsicomex',   2),
('ferrari', 'ferrarieur',   1),
('ferrari', 'ferrarieur',   1),
('ferrari', 'ferrariusa',   0),
('ferrari', 'ferrarimex',   1),
('ferrari', 'ferrarimex',   1);
```

If I run (on dbfiddle):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%sql_mode%';
```

I obtain:

```
Variable_name   Value
sql_mode    ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Note the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (in this case it's the first entry but that's unimportant). Now, if you run the `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%sql_mode%'` command above on your own system it won't have the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` bit. **How** do I know this?

Well, if I try to run your query on dbfiddle:

```
SELECT n_brand , population, actions_u_user
FROM test
WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'
AND actions_u_user > 0
GROUP BY population
```

I get:

```
Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
contains nonaggregated column 'db_1748585530.test.actions_u_user'
which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY
clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

This is because the server setting for `sql_mode` on dbfiddle.uk has been (correctly) set to include the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` option and therefore your query won't work!

You're possibly running a version of MySQL 5.7.x where x is < 5 - see the article [here](https://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2014/09/mysql-575-group-by-respects-functional.html) and also check out the link to an article by the same author ([Debunking GROUP BY myths](http://rpbouman.blogspot.nl/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html)). Read these after finishing this answer - they provide additional clarity on this surprisingly tricky issue!

This (not very useful) query **will** work:

```
SELECT n_brand , population, actions_u_user
FROM test
WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'
AND actions_u_user > 0
GROUP BY n_brand, population, actions_u_user;
```

because, you've `GROUPed BY` **all** of the fields in your `SELECT`.

Result:

```
n_brand     population  actions_u_user
pepsico     pepsicoeur  1
pepsico     pepsicomex  2
pepsico     pepsicousa  1
pepsico     pepsicousa  2
```

So, what's this telling us?

Well, it's telling us that we have one set of values `pepsico   pepsicoeur  1`, one set `pepsico    pepsicomex  2` &c. - i.e. it's one record for each different record (`n_brand`, `population` & `actions_u_user`).

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n_brand, population, actions_u_user
FROM test
WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'
  AND actions_u_user > 0
ORDER BY n_brand, population;
```

Will give the same result (probably cheaper) - see the fiddle.

You can run this, slightly more useful, query (note the `SUM()` aggregate):

```
SELECT n_brand , population, actions_u_user, SUM(actions_u_user) AS sum_p
FROM test
WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'
AND actions_u_user > 0
GROUP BY n_brand, population, actions_u_user;
```

Result:

```
n_brand     population  actions_u_user  sum_p
pepsico     pepsicoeur               1      3
pepsico     pepsicomex               2      2
pepsico     pepsicousa               1      1
pepsico     pepsicousa               2      4
```

Slightly more useful - but the **total** sum of `n_brand` = pepsico with `population` = pepsicousa is 5 (4 + 1), so we're partly on the way to answering the question (see below).

However, to see where the problem lies with **NOT** having `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `sql_mode`, let's remove it!

```
SET sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

So, it's been removed! Now, we rerun your original query:

```
SELECT n_brand , population, actions_u_user
FROM test
WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'
AND actions_u_user > 0
GROUP BY population;
```

and we obtain a **"result"** (this **may or may** not vary depending on your version of MySQL, the time of day, the phases of the moon and the direction the wind happens to blowing!):

```
n_brand     population  actions_u_user
pepsico     pepsicoeur  1
pepsico     pepsicomex  2
pepsico     pepsicousa  1
```

Great you might think, **"I have an answer!"** - indeed you do - but **[WTF is the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)**? You have 3 records, and on inspection, they are actually the **first** record (by `INSERT`ion) for `n_brand` = 'pepsico' and the different `population` records.

MySQL puts an implicit `PRIMARY KEY` on the table (see [here](https://vettabase.com/blog/why-tables-need-a-primary-key-in-mariadb-and-mysql/#Implicit_primary_keys) and the manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html)):

> - If a table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB generates a hidden clustered index named GEN_CLUST_INDEX on a
>   synthetic column that contains row ID values. The rows are ordered by
>   the row ID that InnoDB assigns. The row ID is a 6-byte field that
>   increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. Thus, the rows
>   ordered by the row ID are physically in order of insertion.

and those are the first records by implicit PK which are returned for different values of `population`. But, hey, who knows down the line?

God help you if you rely on this behaviour! It's **not documented** (or rather it's documented as being "undetermined")! If values are `UPDATE`d, what's the result then? `DELETE`d? Result then?

Better **by far** to have a deterministic documented answer - which is what you'll get if you include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in your `sql_mode`.

I like to think of it as providing enough information to the server to provide rational, deterministic answers to SQL queries! If you're **ever** in doubt, do what I do - and test on PostgreSQL, a sane RDBMS!

So, that's that! Set your `sql_mode` to include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and you won't fall into this particular tar-pit!

### Part 2 - the answer to the question:

Let's move on to (far more interesting) aggregation. The five major aggregation [functions are](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/):

- ```
  AVG() – return the average value.
  ```
- ```
  COUNT() – return the number of values.
  ```
- ```
  MAX() – return the maximum value.
  ```
- ```
  MIN() – return the minimum value.
  ```
- ```
  SUM() – return the sum of all or distinct values.
  ```

(set our `sql_mode` back to its original setting - not critical for properly formulated queries, but why not? (See the fiddle)).

So, if we take the `SUM()` (since that's the relevant one here) over all the values in the table, that's all fine and dandy, i.e.

```
SELECT 
  SUM(actions_u_user) AS "The sum of all" 
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
The sum of all
            14
```

but if, as is the case now, you wish to get a `SUM()` over 6 different values of  `n_brand` & `population`, you have to **`GROUP BY`** these values, otherwise what do these `SUM()`s correspond to?

So, we run this:

```
SELECT 
  n_brand AS "The Brand",      

  -- for presentation purposes. With multi-word aliases, 
  -- you have to use double quotes! I use them all the time anyway!

  population AS "Population", 
  SUM(actions_u_user) AS "The column name"  

  -- or AS col_name - no quotes necessary if there are no
  -- spaces in the column alias
    
FROM test
GROUP BY n_brand, population
ORDER BY n_brand, population;
```

Result:

```
The Brand   Population  The column name
ferrari     ferrarieur                2
ferrari     ferrarimex                2
ferrari     ferrariusa                0
pepsico     pepsicoeur                3
pepsico     pepsicomex                2
pepsico     pepsicousa                5
6 rows
```

So, now we have the `SUM()` of `actions_u_user` over the entire table for a given value of `n_brand` & `population`. Finally, we can refine this query to return the desired result set - we're only interested in `pepsico` and where the `SUM() is > 0`, hence:

```
SELECT 
  n_brand AS "The Brand",      

  -- for presentation purposes. With multi-word aliases, 
  -- you have to use double quotes! 

  population AS "Population", 
  SUM(actions_u_user) AS "The column name"  

  -- or AS col_name - no quotes necessary if there are no
  -- spaces in the column alias
    
FROM test

WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'  -- added these two lines
  AND actions_u_user > 0

GROUP BY n_brand, population
ORDER BY n_brand, population;
```

Result:

```
The Brand   Population  The column name
  pepsico   pepsicoeur                3
  pepsico   pepsicomex                2
  pepsico   pepsicousa                5
```

Which is the desired result!

I would urge you to study up on, and master, aggregate functions - they are the "bread and butter" of SQL and will lead on to stuff such as [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) (and other goodies) which are ever more powerful ways of moving your data up to the apex of the [DIKW pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIKW_pyramid)!

Finally, I would urge you to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887460/select-list-is-not-in-group-by-clause-and-contains-nonaggregated-column-inc/41887524) to see the perils of not having `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set in MySQL - I have seen gurus say that in the hands of an expert, it can be OK to unset it - personally, I wouldn't... why bother for starters?

Queries can provide meaningful results without having to resort to this abomination... so I say **no**! YMMV! Or just switch to PostgreSQL! However, see the article by Roland Bouman ([Debunking GROUP BY myths](https://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html)) cited above for an alternative viewpoint and a neat workaround. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594865/is-mysql-breaking-the-standard-by-allowing-selecting-columns-that-are-not-part-o/7596265#7596265) will provide further explanation.

p.s. welcome to dba.se and +1 - this answer forced me to marshall my thoughts! p.p.s. in future, when asking a question, could you please provide a working fiddle - it helps to have a [single point of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) for a question and eliminates duplication of effort - help us to help you!

Comment: "t appears that MySQL putsf an implicit PRIMARY KEY ... But, hey, who knows?" Well, I'm not 100% sure why you doubt it, but it's easy to verify that clustered indexes exist :) 
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/3290a66c89eb1625a7058e0ef732432b6952b435/storage/innobase/row/row0vers.cc#L71

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli - I've removed the "It appears" and rephrased -it was more of a literary flourish than an expression of doubt! :-) Molte grazie!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT n_brand, population, SUM(actions_completed_by_unique_user) as actions
  FROM agg_table
 WHERE n_brand = 'pepsico'
 GROUP BY n_brand, population
```

There's no need for `actions_completed_by_unique_user > 0` unless you have negative values. I also assume that `n_brand` is the same as `platform`.